# Solr Sunspot- specify which fields to return in the result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm using Sunspot Solr for indexing and searching in our Ruby on Rails application with MongoDB database (Mongo mapper)

Every time I queried Solr for result, it sends back the entire document content about the article stored in the database, which makes the query very slow.

What i want to do is to include only specific fields to the query.

I found that [fl](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) can be used to specify a set of fields to return but i'm getting an error, see blow:

```
searchable :if => :published do
  text :title, :boost => 5
end

def self.search_keywords keywords
  search = Top.search do
    fulltext keywords
    adjust_solr_params do |params|
      params[:fl] = "title_text"
    end
  end
  search.results
end
```

Solr Request :

```
  SOLR Request (24.9ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Top"], q: "test", fl: "title_text", qf: "title_text", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]
```

Error :

> undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add parameter "id" in fl because hits block need id parameter to parse the results.